# installing HDFS for use with SHARK without YARN

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, apache-spark, shark-sql

I'm trying to install Apache Shark. One of the requirement is to have HDFS installed. 
I don't want to use YARN or MESOS. I just want HDFS. My question is:
Does this mean I can only install hadoop distribution prior to 2.x? If so, which one?

or can I use Hadoop 2.4 and somehow disable YARN? I'm not really sure how to do this. All the tutorial I can find seem to use YARN. does anyone have any suggestion on how to use HDFS only with 2.x? which hadoop distribution do I need if just want to install HDFS?

Answer (score 0):

To use shark you need to install :

- HDFS to store data
- Hive
- Spark for in-memory usage

Yarn is not mandatory

Comment: so, how do i make YARN not mandatory then? do I specify this in mapred-site.xml?

    <configuration>
    <property>
    <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
    <value>localhost:9001</value>
    </property>
    </configuration>

Comment: just don't start or install mapreduce service.